# Creating a pipeline in R that serially processes multiple csv files

Tags: r, csv, pipeline

My pipeline reads in a csv to a dataframe, assigns rownames, removes a column, performs a pca, plots the pca and extracxts the meaningful variables from the pca which are also plotted.
Here is my current code, which only goes as far as the first plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

tsv = read.csv('matrix.tsv', sep='\t')
bell= read.csv('bell.tsv', sep='\t')
tail= read.csv('tail.tsv', sep='\t')

dfList = list(tail, tsv, bell)
#process csv's
dfList = lapply(dfList, function(dum){
  rownames(dum) = dum[,1]
  dum[,1] = NULL
  dum$X = NULL
  dum = dum[, -grep('un', colnames(dum))]
})
#create pca's of dataframes
pcaList = lapply(dfList, function(pca){
  prin_comp = prcomp(pca, scale. = T)
})
#plot top 2 principle components in the pca
plotList = lapply(pcaList, function(prin_comp){
  t = qplot(x=prin_comp$rotation[,1], y=prin_comp$rotation[,2]) + geom_text_repel(aes(label=row.names(prin_comp$rotation)))
})
#this plots the 3 plots, one for each pca, but they are un-named
plotList
```

The problem is that the plots don't have meaningful names/titles. I don't know how to keep that information present, passed from function to function.
I know there must be a more elegant way of doing this. And I have spent a day reading similar and not so similar questions regarding processing multiple csv files. But either they weren't applicable or didn't work for my case.
And as the title of this question implies, I would prefer to do this on one csv at a time, not all 3 at a time, as the csv's in question are very large, over 5GB each, so keeping each dataframe and pca in memory at the same time is impossible.

Comment: Can you clarify the behavior you are looking for?  Do you want the plot objects to have meaningful names, or do you want there to be a title on the plot and to save that somewhere? or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to keep a string you want to use as the title somewhere and add `ggtitle(YOUR_TITLE)` to your plot, but this is not so easy with your current code. Instead of performing each step of the analysis for each CSV before going to the next step, why don't you just perform all steps for one CSV at a time?

Your code could look like:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)

csvs <- c("matrix.tsv","bell.tsv","tail.tsv")
for (i in csvs) {
  # read file
  df <- read.csv(i, sep='\t')
  # process file
  rownames(df) <- df[,1]
  df[,1] <- NULL
  df$X = NULL
  df = df[, -grep('un', colnames(df))]
  # create pca
  pca <- prcomp(df, scale = T)
  # plot pca
  pcaPlot <- qplot(x=pca$rotation[,1], y=pca$rotation[,2]) +
             geom_text_repel(aes(label=row.names(pca$rotation))) +
             ggtitle(i)
  print(pcaPlot)
  # extract and plot meaningful variables
  # ...
}
```

Basically I just put everything you do in a `lapply` call inside of a `for` loop, this approach also does the processing for one CSV at the time.

Comment: Very nice! When I tried the for loop method, I used a list of data frames instead of an array, which didn't work.
I found one problem in your code: I changed `pca` to `prin_comp`.
and now I have a question: when I call `pcaPlot` inside the loop, it fails to display in the plot (I'm using RStudio).

Comment: @Glubbdrubb i forgot that when using ggplot in a `for` loop you need to print the plot, so just add a line `print(pcaPlot)` after the plot was created. And regarding the name of the variable `pca` i edited the answer

Comment: I also stripped the extension from the file name, which makes it more useful downstream, like this:
`placeHoler = strsplit(i, "\\.")`   `my_title = placeHoler[[1]][1]`.
Then `my_title` is used in stead of `i` for the plot title.